# How to start cosmosdb emulator from command line?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I installed the emulator according to this and following this guide. I am starting here: Use the emulator on Linux or macOS. [cosmos docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=cli%2Cssl-netstd21#running-the-emulator-on-a-local-network)I can start the cosmosdb emulator from the windows menu. However I need to start it and make the port exposed to my macbook so my dev environment can connect to it. To do this I see you have to start the emulator from the command line. But if I try to run it from the command line it says

> command not found

Why do I get this error given that I have installed it correctly according to the docs? How do I start it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is just above the section you referred to in your question in the docs.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM +4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
```

Make sure to read and follow these instructions carefully. There are multiple steps involved in running the emulator hosted in a Windows VM from Mac or Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have run that command according to the directions. And I get an error: The term 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe' is not recognized as the name of
a cmdlet, function ... when i run that in powershell

Comment: Oh I see. Im not a windows user so didnt realize. You have to be in the same folder as the exeutable. In addition you cant just run the command as is. You have to run it like this. .\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM +4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==

Comment: Yes, either that or add it to the path env var.